# Markowitz w/ riskless asset & CAPM

Tags: capm, markowitz

If risk free rate ($R_0$) is bigger than expected return on minimum variance portfolio ($\bar{\mu}$), so $R_0>\bar{\mu}$. I.e. the tanget portfolio is on the risky inefficient portfolio frontier and we want to short sell risky portfolio. Question 1: Why is this not consistent with CAPM? Question 2: Is it consistent with general notion of securities market equilibrium??

Comment: What do you think and why?

Answer (score 1):

This situation is not consistent with equilibrium at all because any investors should be hold always and only short position in risky assets. Who buy them? 
Note that in *long only* case, the usual, the firms sell their stock.

As a consequence also CAPM equilibrium not hold, even if CAPM equation can be derived yet. 
Read this related topic:
 [Under the CAPM, how do I deal with market returns being below the risk-free rate?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/21625/under-the-capm-how-do-i-deal-with-market-returns-being-below-the-risk-free-rate/27475#27475)